# While compiling jsp WebLogic 12c throw error

Tags: java, jsp, java-8, weblogic12c

```
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /jspnew/loans/loanRepayment.jsp
loanRepayment.jsp:383:143: This attribute is not recognized.
                                                                branchBtnDisabled=""  branchDescName="" branchDescValue="<%=branchDesc%>" branchDescCssClass = "FieldTextRO" branchTabIndex="<%=""+tabIndex++%>" branchDescReadonly="true" branchDescTabIndex="-1"
                                                                                                                                                                                                      ^------^
loanRepayment.jsp:386:122: This attribute is not recognized.
                                                                moduleDescName=""  moduleDescValue="<%=moduleDesc%>" moduleDescCssClass = "FieldTextRO" moduleTabIndex="<%=""+tabIndex++%>"   moduleDescReadonly="true" moduleDescTabIndex="-1"
                                                                                                                                                                                 ^------^
loanRepayment.jsp:389:121: This attribute is not recognized.
                                                                schemeDescName="" schemeDescValue="<%=schemeDesc%>" schemeDescCssClass = "FieldTextRO" schemeTabIndex="<%=""+tabIndex++%>" schemeDescReadonly="true" schemeDescTabIndex="-1"
                                                                                                                                                                                ^------^
loanRepayment.jsp:392:133: This attribute is not recognized.
                                                                acctNoDescName="" acctNoDescValue="<%=custAcct.getNameLong()%>" acctNoDescCssClass = "FieldTextRO" acctNoTabIndex="<%=""+tabIndex++%>" acctNoDescReadonly="true" acctNoDescTabIndex="-1" noInputRequired="true"/>
                                                                                                                                                                                            ^------^

    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.reportCompilationErrorIfNeccessary(JavelinxJSPStub.java:247)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.compilePage0(JavelinxJSPStub.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.access$000(JavelinxJSPStub.java:50)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub$1.run(JavelinxJSPStub.java:111)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.compilePage(JavelinxJSPStub.java:108)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:267)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:218)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.getServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:414)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:304)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:489)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:376)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at dm.web.utils.SecurityCheck.doFilter(SecurityCheck.java:126)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Comment: What is in your JSP? Especially  /jspnew/loans/loanRepayment.jsp (loanRepayment.jsp:383:143)?

Comment: when I write something like      type="<%=ics.GetVar("c")%>"      Then above error show.

Comment: Your errorcode indicates there is something amiss with the following code:
` branchTabIndex="<%=""+tabIndex++%>" ` (and some more tabIndex++ occurrences)

Comment: Thanks a lot mylenereiners.
I found soln for my problem. In weblogic there is a setting for old jsp code. backward jsp compatibility have to select from weblogic console.

Comment: @Yuwi can you please let us the backward compatible settings in weblogic?

Comment: Hey @user3198603 here is menu path-

Home >base_domain –>
Under “Web Applications”  Tab –> JSP Compiler Backwards Compatible

it may solve ur problem.

Comment: @Yuwi do we need to redeploy the war file again, after changing backward compatible setting.

Comment: @shan Yes we need to redeploy war file again

Answer (score 1):

I found soln for this problem. In weblogic there is a setting for old jsp code. backward jsp compatibility have to select from weblogic console.
Here is menu path- Home >base_domain –> Under “Web Applications” Tab –> JSP Compiler Backwards Compatible it may solve ur problem.