# Error in "yyy.jspf" at line 7: The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic11g

We are using weblogic server 11g and this jsp file was working with jdk1.6. Now, when we tried to upgrade to JDK1.8, the weblogic is throwing this exception, when I hit the login page. The same code is working fine with Tomcat9.0 container. Tried two solutions like

1. Added source and target options for javac([The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved in package declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration))
2. Selected JSP Compiler Backwards Compatible option under web applications tab of domain ([While compiling jsp WebLogic 12c throw error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734677/while-compiling-jsp-weblogic-12c-throw-error))

but it none of them worked. Can anyone please help me to find a solution for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Full Stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /WEB-INF/web/en/US/enterpriseMgr/Login/xxx.jsp
xxx.jsp:2:18: Error in "yyy.jspf" at line 7: The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
<%@ include file="../../common/yyy.jspf"%>
                 ^-----------------------------^
xxx.jsp:2:18: Error in "yyy.jspf" at line 96: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
<%@ include file="../../common/yyy.jspf"%>
                 ^-----------------------------^
```

Comment: Add some code of your xxx.jsp and yyy.jspf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is related to an incompatibility between the WebLogic 11g JSP compiler and JDK 1.8.

See other details and a workaround from my answer to a similar error related to the same incompatibility: [java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved Error using Java 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170904/1996150).